# how to pass basic authentication in webservice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a webservice which has a method to return a value.Here my requirement is , I want to pass the authentication value in header for each and every web request i used the below given code for doing the same

```
req = WebRequest.Create(http://localhost/test/test.asmx);
string _auth = string.Format("{0}:{1}", "username", "password");
string _enc = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_auth));
string _cred = string.Format("{0} {1}", "Basic", _enc);
req.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = _cred;
WebResponse response = (WebResponse)req.GetResponse();
```

But through this way I am not able to call the webmethod. Is there any way to achieve the same.

Also I tried to sending the authentication values with the help of ICredentials with the following given code , but i need the header values like "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4="

```
 ICredentials creds;
 creds = new
 NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
 proxy.Credentials = creds;
 string str=proxy.helloworld();
```

please let me know if there is any way to achieve this..any help is appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Copying from [this post](http://intellitect.com/calling-web-services-using-basic-authentication/).

```
protected override System.Net.WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
{
    HttpWebRequest request;
    request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(uri);

    if (PreAuthenticate)
    {
        NetworkCredential networkCredentials =
              Credentials.GetCredential(uri, “Basic”);

        if (networkCredentials != null)
        {
            byte[] credentialBuffer = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(
                 networkCredentials.UserName + “:” +
                 networkCredentials.Password);
            request.Headers["Authorization"] =
                 “Basic” + Convert.ToBase64String(credentialBuffer);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(“No network credentials”);
        }
    }
    return request;
}
```